# how to extract only specific value from google search link?

Tags: jquery

I want to extract "start" value from a google search link. How can i do this in jquery. This below link having value of start=20 and i only want 20 from this string.

https://www.google.com/search?q=python+code&ei=yGQsXL7yIMnQwQLis4CoAQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwi-9tOmxs7fAhVJaFAKHeIZABU4ChDy0wMIew&biw=1242&bih=569

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/19491336/5052778

Answer (score 1):

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=python+code&ei=yGQsXL7yIMnQwQLis4CoAQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwi-9tOmxs7fAhVJaFAKHeIZABU4ChDy0wMIew&biw=1242&bih=569';

function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
    var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

var start = getParameterByName('start', url);

console.log(start);
```

Comment: up1 for the quick and easy answer. thanks